The solution of the heat equation for data in $\mathcal{S}'$.

Compute the fundamental solution of the initial value problem for the heat equation,
$$ \frac{\partial G}{\partial t} - \Delta G = 0, \quad (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^d \times (0,\infty), $$
with the initial condition,
$$ G(x,0) = f(x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d.$$
:

i) - Show that this formula makes sense for $f \in \mathcal{S}′$ (i.e. $f$ is a tempered distribution).
ii) - Show that the solution $u(x, t)$ of this problem is in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d\times (0, \infty) )$
for any initial data in $\mathcal{S}'.$
Solution
the fundamental solution to this system is:
$$u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} G(x-y,t) f(y) \, dy,$$
where
$G(x,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}} \exp\left(-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}\right).$
My question is about what should I show as an answer for (i) and (ii)? I would answer as follows:
i) intuitively, $G$ is a smooth function (not compactly supported), and $f$ decays fast then the integral is always well-defined. However, I suspect that the answer should be in distribution sense. So, since $f \in \mathcal{S}'$ then
$$f*G(x)=\langle f, \tau_x RG\rangle,$$
where $\tau_x$, $R$ are the translation and rotation operators.
the above is not convincing since $G$ is not a test function?? What should I do.
For point (ii) I think the situation is easer,
$$D^\alpha f*G(x) = \langle D^\alpha f, \tau_x RG\rangle = (-1)^\alpha \langle f,D^\alpha \tau_x RG\rangle= \langle f,\tau_x RD^\alpha G\rangle .$$
Thanks in advance...

I'd think of $u$ as $u : [0, \infty) \to \mathcal{S}'$. This is one way you can make sense of "initial data in $\mathcal{S}'$.

@Mason I did not get what do you meaning!
